# JasperReports Server: How to limit the date input for calendar

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Does anyone know of a way I can limit the popup calendar in *JasperReports Server* to only allow for choosing a past date of less than 3 months ago?

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: You can look at this posts: [Adding a filter to custom datasource](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/adding-filter-custom-datasource) and [Using Groovy in a Filter Expression](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-groovy-filter-expression)

Comment: You can also try to modify the `webapps\jasperserver-pro\wcf\calendar\calendar.js`

Comment: I don't see how Alex K's comments addresses the question. The question is regarding validation of input value, not filtering of data sources. Does any one have another answer other than modifying calendar.js. That won't work, because every instance of the calendar will likely have different validation rules.